# object Error on epenusing dojo.xhrPost and dijit.byID together in IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, dojo

I am new in DOJO and facing some problem on using dojo.xhrPost and dijit.byID together.
Any pointer highly appreciated.

Using two functions, both are working fine independently but on using them together. I'm getting "object error" on IE6.

See below two function

```
function submitForm(obj,form){  
dojo.xhrPost( {
    url : pageFlowURL,
    preventCache : true,
    timeout : ajaxTimeout,
    form : pageFormElem,
    load : function(response, ioArgs) {
        if (condition) {
                    do something...
        }else{ 
        loaderCheck();  
        }
        },
        error: function(error) {
        // an error has occurred
        alert("error : "+error);
            }
});
}

function loader() {  
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
if (!parsed) {
    dojo.parser.parse(dijit.byId("loaderdiv"));
    parsed = true;
}  
alert(dijit.byId("loaderdiv"));
loaderdiv = dijit.byId("loaderdiv"); 
loaderdiv.titleBar.style.display = "none"; 
dijit.byId("loaderdiv").show(); 
dojo.addClass("dijit_DialogUnderlay_0", ["loaderdiv_underlay"]);}
```

getting "object error" in **(IE6)** function loader() on line
**loaderdiv = dijit.byId("loaderdiv");**

whereas getting successful alert just above that on code **alert(dijit.byId("loaderdiv"));**

HTML code is:

```
<div id="loaderdiv" class="tundra" dojoType="dijit.Dialog">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the dijit.Dialog has a titleBar property?  According to the docs http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit.Dialog it doesn't...  It sounds more like you're getting an error trying to set style.display on the undefined loaderDiv.titleBar...
(You can test by alerting loaderDiv.titleBar or by using a more modern browser's built-in debugging console).

Comment: yes, dijit.Dialog have this property and as i said both functions are working fine independently. Problem is in using them together, like i m using **loader()** in **function submitForm(obj,form)**.